# Option for Union datatype in C#

Tags: c#, types, union

I have implemented one program in C++ which has union Datatype.
Now I want to convert that program into c#.

I want to used same structure in c# but don't know what can be used in place of union datatype.

We are using Visual Studio 2013 and framework 4.5.2.0

Answer (score 1):

There is no *out-of-the-box* `Union` *data type* in C#

However, you can fake-it with a `struct` and the `FieldOffset` *attribute* I guess. You can do this because of the need for interoperability, also you sometimes see it  used for a fast *non-cast* type conversion. Be warned though, it's considered **extremely hacky**.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct SomeType
{
   [FieldOffset(0)] public int Myint;
   [FieldOffset(0)] public byte Byte1;
   [FieldOffset(1)] public byte Byte2;
   [FieldOffset(2)] public byte Byte3;
   [FieldOffset(3)] public byte Byte4;

}
```

**Usage**

```
var someType = new SomeType();

Console.WriteLine(someType.Myint);

someType.Byte1 = 2;
Console.WriteLine(someType.Myint);

someType.Byte2 = 4;
Console.WriteLine(someType.Myint);
```

**Output**

```
0
2
1026
```

<sub>***Note** : I would seriously consider using the more common language features in C#, rethink the problem and not use this hack.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, C# provides no direct out of the "box solution" in comparison to C++' `Union` data type.  However, `BitConverter` is an option if you're using the union to map the bytes of one of the types of the other.

For example:

```
int x = 15;
float y = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(x), 0);
```

& vice versa:

```
float y = 15f;
int x = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(y), 0);
```